# Bootstrap Accordion broken after upgrade

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been looking around forums to try and find something similar but haven't been able to pin it down. Here's code block with my code simplified:

```
<div id="line-up" class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button m-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main" data-parent="#line-up"><p>Mainstage</p></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button m-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dub" data-parent="#line-up"><p>Dub Castle</p></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button m-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#kids" data-parent="#line-up"><p>Kids Village</p></button>
            <p class="mt-2 mb-2"><span class="text-danger">The line-up is <u>not</u> complete!</span> Estimated date of completion is June.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="collapse show indent" id="main">
                XXX
            </div>
            <div class="collapse indent" id="dub">
                YYY
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="kids">
                ZZZ
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I used [THIS code pen](https://codepen.io/etrain/pen/BZdYwa) to test out if my bootstrap CSS or JS files were at fault.

This code worked fine with Bootstrap CSS & JS until I upgraded from 4.0.0 to 4.2.1. I haven't been able to figure out the issue. The buttons at the top are meant to switch between XXX, YYY and ZZZ with XXX being visible at the beginning and being hidden when either YYY or ZZZ are brought up.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The `data-parent` changed after 4.1. It should be placed in the collapsible div instead of the collapse toggle...

```
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="collapse show indent" id="main" data-parent="#line-up">
        XXX
    </div>
    <div class="collapse indent" id="dub" data-parent="#line-up">
        YYY
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="kids" data-parent="#line-up">
        ZZZ
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/BPfTFHAj4E

Comment: Thanks! That seems logical. I hadn't noticed it in the notes.